# How to make good rune pages for general use

Tags: league-of-legends

I watch a lot of streams and I see many people like TheOddOne and Guardsman Bob using a bunch of mixed up rune pages. Are there all around good in general rune setups to be used for say an AP carry, AP Tank, Support, etc.?

I just find myself with only about 8 rune pages never being able to have the runes i need for a champion I am usually forced to pick to compliment my team, instead of being ready to use whomever I would like or be more comfortable with the champs I am forced to use.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have space for eight pages and want to cover most of the basic roles, here are some six general rune pages:

**Support**

- Quints: +1 GP/10
- Marks: Flat armor
- Seals: +1.41 Armor
- Glyphs: +1.34 Magic Resist

**Ranged AD Carry**

- Quints: +2.25 Attack Damage
- Marks: +.95 Attack Damage
- Seals: +1.41 Armor
- Glyphs: +1.34 Magic Resist

**Manaless AP**

- Quints: +4.95 Ability Power
- Marks: +.95 Magic Penetration
- Seals: +1.08 Health per Level
- Glyphs: +0.17 Ability Power per Level

**Tank Jungler**

- Quints: +1.5% Movement Speed
- Marks: +1.7% Attack Speed
- Seals: +1.41 Armor
- Glyphs: +1.34 Magic Resist

**Mana AP**

- Quints: +4.95 Ability Power
- Marks: +.95 Magic Penetration
- Seals: +.065 Mana Per Level
- Glyphs: +15 Magic Resist Per Level

**AD Jungle**

- Quints: +3.4% Attack Speed
- Marks: +1.66 Armor Penetration x6, 1.7% Attack Speed x3
- Seals: +1.41 Armor
- Glyphs: +1.34 Magic Resist

This leaves you two champion specific pages for people who are special like Akali.

Comment: Thank you this is going to help me play much better having a standard go with runes.

Comment: No problem.  Upvote if it was helpful.  Also, for some of the Champion specific setups, you can check my LOLKing.net page: http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/33114#runes

Answer (score 1):

**Your doing it wrong, NO, the way your doing it, it's wrong.**

You should not be customizing your rune pages per champ, there are over one hundred champions, and I sincerly doubt you have the time or the inclination to buy over one hundred rune pages and customize them for each champion.

Furthermore that would be even more complicated than it initially seems, as many champions can fulfill multiple roles which means they would need a different rune page for each role.

Rather, I would do as is suggested in the linked question, and make general purpose rune pages for the different ROLES in the game, and apply the appropriate page to whatever niche your champion is going to fill in the game.

Some thoughts on to the roles:

Is your champion goin to be Offensive (Damage dealer), Defensive (Tank), or a balance of the two?

Does your champion focus on Attack Damage or Ability power to deal damage? (Or is your champion a hybrid?)

Is the enemy team heavy on AD or AP? Because of this, should your defense be focused on Armor or Magic Resist?

Are you jungling?

Does your champion have something special about him\her that calls for a unique rune page? (IE: lots of people swear that Move Speed Quints are mandatory for Skarner)

It's important to note that while some Mastery and Rune choices are no brainers, many are not. And what works for someone else might not neccesarily work for you. In the end it's a matter of personal preference above all else. **Take what works for you, and experiment often to find new strategies and ideas.**

Final Note: You should NEVER buy anything but Tier 3 runes, as any runes bought during Tier 1 or 2 will simply be phased out when you can purchase Tier 3 runes. Best to save your IP until your level 20 instead of wasting it on runes your eventually going to discard anyway.

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89795/learning-how-to-buy-runes/89799#89799) question may offer some help as well.

Answer (score 0):

This Link will answer all your questions:
http://www.reignofgaming.net/blogs/a-different-view/vvinrar/20561-runes-to-win-2-the-essential-rune-kit-for-lolpros

You need about 4 or 5 rune pages to cover every lane, the others can be used for special cases (like Galio, more MR etc)

Comment: Thank you this is going to help me alot with my extra more specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

timlans runes were exellent but i wanna add one page into solotop
Armor Marks
Armor seals
Mr per level glyphs
Health regen/5 quintessences

This is really good on lategame orientated solotop late nasus irelia etc.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment Buritan, but I wouldn't recommend those runes for Nasus.  Hyfe's Nasus guide is definitive and he recommends very different runes.  Feel free to take a look here: http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=151

Answer (score 0):

Well actually no, there is not general rune pages that work well on all characters. Ability to understand nuances that really make champion great against enemy champion(s) on lane, create the biodiversity that this game has.

In addition to following builds you should know runes are cost effectiveness (so you get the most bang for the buck). For example mana regen per level seals are most efficient runes, but you only need them for champions who use a lot of mana and/or need to get by without blue buff.

In following 3 builds, Supports can run with jungle runes. x3 Gold quints get you 18 gold per minute or 360 gold at 20 minute mark. So it is much much better to have extra armor and/movement speed. 3 gold quints give you money about equal to 1 cs on every 4 waves.

**AD**

> **Magic resist at level 18** 13.5 (rounds to 13)
>
> **Magic resist** 5.36 (rounds to 5.4)
>
> **Physical damage** 14.67 (rounds to 15)
>
> **Movement Speed** 3%

- Quints:

  - x2 +1.5% Movement Speed
  - x1 +2.25 Attack
- Marks:

  - x9 0.95 Attack
- Seals:

  - x9 0.45 Attack
- Glyphs:

  - x4 0.45 Magic Resist
  - x5 0.15 Magic Resist per level (2.7 at level 18)

**AP**

> **Mana regen /5 at level 18** 10.53 (rounds to 11)
>
> **Ability Power** 26
>
> **Magic Penetration** 8.5

- Quints:

  - x3 +4.95 Ability Power
- Marks:

  - x9 +0.95 Magic Penetration
- Seals:

  - x9 +0.065 Mana regeneration per level (1.17 at level 18)
- Glyphs:

  - x9 +1.19 Ability Power

**Jungle**

> **Magic resist at level 18** 10.8 (rounds to 11)
>
> **Movement Speed** 3%
>
> **Armor** 20.45 (rounds to 20)
>
> **Attack** 8.55

- Quints:

  - x2 +1.5% Movement Speed
  - x1 +4.26 Armor
- Marks:

  - x9 0.95 Attack
- Seals:

  - x9 1.41 Armor
- Glyphs:

  - x4 0.45 Magic Resist per level (2.7 at level 18)
  - x5 0.7 Armor

Losing like 2-3 waves of minions ~equal to worth of all runes. This is reason why jungler camping bot usally wins - if enemy ad needs to back or dies, then enemy support can be zoned out and x2 people lose wave exp and gold.

Comment: What about tank def heroes?