# How do I customize runes per champ or for general purpose?

Tags: league-of-legends

There has been something that has bothered me since i learned about runes. Let's say I buy runes that were recommended in a guide for Annie or Ahri. What if I choose to play say Teemo or another champion? I mean I'd be using runes intended for a mage, but I'd be playing a non-mage.

**So how do I customize runes per champ or for general purpose?** Also, [I'm aware of this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78003/how-to-make-good-rune-pages-for-general-use), but I don't think it answers my question completely.

Comment: Your question is not really that different. If you want to play AP Teemo, you use the same rune page. If you don't, you don't use it. Teemo is a mage if you want him to be, he's not an exception to assembling general AP or AD bruiser rune pages. You either have to make general rune pages as suggested in the linked duplicate, or purchase a large number of rune pages to allow finer customization and optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a single rune page for 500 RP (Riot Points) or 6300 IP (Influence Points). The other option is 7 Rune Page bundle for 2600 RP. Riot some times runs special where you one rune page is buy one get one free.

I have 5 pages setup:

AP/Mana Regen (usually for mid consisting of AP, mana regen and magic pen)
Dmg (usually for ADCs Consisting of Attack damage and Attack Speed)
Noc ( For jungle Noc he is kinda unique on what he wants Armor Pen and attack speed )
Mundo (Really my Bruiser/Tank Rune set Armor , Health and Magic Pen)
Support ( For support mostly GP Qunits/ Mana Regen and Health)